# The way dummy symbols apply for DataFrame name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, macos, numpy

I want to apply dummy symbol to DataFrame name and query method

```
for t in range(10):
    df**t**=df.query("columns name==**t**")
```

Please tell me the way dummy symbol apply to DataFrame name and query method

I tried  `"df{}".format(t)=df.query(columns name==t)`

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to generate variables dynamically, use a dictionary:

```
dfs = {i: df.loc[df['columns name'].eq(t)] for t in range(10)}
```

Or with query, as corrected by @jezrael:

```
dfs = {i: df.query('`columns name` == @t') for t in range(10)}
```

Then slice your desired dataframes with:

```
dfs[0]
```

*NB. if the indices are only consecutive numbers, use a list:*

```
dfs = [df.loc[df['columns name'].eq(t)] for t in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `@` for select variable with `` if column names with spaces:

```
for t in range(10): 
    dft=df.query("`columns name`==@t")
```